# Algorithm for LMI optimization of PSD matrix

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

To optimize a PSD $(n,n)$ matrix $ X $, we are asked us to propose (give ), implement and compare different Algorithms for the resolution of a Linear matrix inequality given by:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} X & B\\ {{B^T}}&{C + t  I}\end{array}}\right) \succeq 0\\ & X \succeq 0\\ & t \geq 0\end{array}$$

where $C$ is an $m \times m$ symmetric matrix and $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix, and $I$ is the identity matrix.

The objective is to find the PSD matrix $X$ and the parametre $t$ that satisfy those constraints.

Comment: the optimization parametre is the PSD matrix $X$

Comment: And $t$, I assume.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the subject of this homework its to implement those algorithm in matlab ou python  and understand the complexity of each one .